# The model change does not trigger the change in collection

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-relational

I have two different view (1), (2)
1) it shows the list of users
2) it shows the detail of users

In the (2) is possible to change the name.
Then I would expect that the correspondent item in the (1) change accordingly, but it does not.

How should fix/debug the problem?

Here my essential code:

```
// list of users (1)
View_1 = Backbone.View.extend({
    collection: new MyCollection(),
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.bind('add', this.addOne);
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.addAll);
    }
});

// user detail (2)
View_2 = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: new MyModel()
});

MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: new MyModel()
});
```

Comment: You don't seem to be binding to a `change` event in `View_1`...?

Comment: As you are initializing the `View.collection` I'm wondering if you replace it with a new `Collection` in some point before start to add data to it. I mean if you change the Collection which the _reference_ is targeting to.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind a `change` event to the collection. Right now you only bind `reset` and `add`, so things will only update when a new model is added to the collection, or when the collection is initialized with starting values.

```
this.collection.bind('change', this.render);
```

Or something like that, to trigger rendering whatever needs to change.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I did try but it does not work? Do you have some idea why? or how can I test it?

Comment: @LorraineBernard Can you elaborate in the question what exactly you tried? You'll want to put some `console.log` calls in the callback to check that it gets called on change. Also, I was assuming before that this code you posted was just an example, but to confirm, you also need to add the models to the collection properly.